# How do I beat endless level 44 in Frozen Free Fall?

Tags: frozen-free-fall

We have been stuck at endless level 44 of *Frozen Free Fall* (iOS) for a while. The level requires collecting three types of cream to form ice creams. The top one is easy. But the middle and bottom ones are hard to get. Are there any tips for this level?

[image: screenshot of level]